# Deleting objects from a vector at a given index

Tags: c++, object, vector

I have several classes, and several vectors holding a few of each type of object. For simplicity, I'll just talk about one. So I have:

```
class Multiple : public Question {
    public:
        //Member functions here
    private:
        int num_choices;
        string correct;
        vector<string> choices;
};
```

It also inherits a few data members, `int points;`, `int chapter;` and `string prompt;`.

So I have `vector<Multiple> mcq;` to store several objects of the class (not dynamically allocated). But now I need to be able to delete an object at a given index, I have tried just `mcq.erase(index)` but using Visual Studio 2012 it gives the error `Error: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=Multiple, _Alloc = std::allocator<Multiple>]" matches the argument list argument types are: (int) object type is: std::vector<Multiple, std::allocator<Multiple>>` and I have no idea what it means or how to fix it.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: try mcq.erase( mcq.begin() + index );

Comment: erase wants an iterator http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: If in doubt, look at [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).

Answer (score 4):

The `erase` method does not take an index but an iterator position. You should do:

```
mcq.erase(mcq.begin() + index)
```